# Error when run my python file from command line

Tags: python, debian, pycharm

I have pyCharm project in which all of my folders have an `__init__.py` file, and so they are in the Python package.

When I right click on my bootstrap python file and run it, everything runs correctly, but when I execute "python server.py" from the command line I get the error:

> /usr/bin/python: No module named agent_module.server_command

How can I run my project from command line?

Comment: You are getting that error because _agent_module_ is not in `sys.path`. Maybe try something like `PYTHONPATH= python server.py`. (This command tells Python to look for modules in the current directory; if it doesn't work, please tell us where _server.py_ is and where _agent_module_ is.)